# how to customize windows login authentication method

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, authentication, windows-authentication

I want to add more functionality to windows login screen, like adding 2 factor authentication and like this, is it possible in windows? and how can I get such api. note that I need a c++ api

Comment: Which OS? GINA or a credential provider are your two main options.

Comment: for windows 7, 8 and windows servers from 2008 till 2012